# How to set time interval to UISlider of 0.02

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uislider

I need to set time interval of 0.02 to UISlider and in valueChanged method i need to reflect something when value of slider changes exactly to 0.02 .Like 0.02 ,0.04,0.08....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both positive and negative values in slider.
So all above answers are not useful for me.
Even i cant compare slider's old and new value 's difference with ==.
So this is another issue.

This is my working code.

```
float incDecTempoVal=0.02;
float val_tempo=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",sliderBMP.value] floatValue];

if (sliderBMP.value<0.0) 
    sliderBMP.value=sliderBMP.value-(incDecTempoVal-fabs(fmod(val_tempo,incDecTempoVal)));

else 
    sliderBMP.value=sliderBMP.value+(incDecTempoVal-fabs(fmod(val_tempo, incDecTempoVal)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (sender.value == 2)
    {
        //do something here 

    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I just realized that comparing floats are just a pain in c and objective-c.  So If I were you, I would use an int (2) instead of a float (0.02) and cast the int to a float when you need it for your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve discrete values in `UISlider`you need to handle this logic in your `valueChanged` method. For example

```
-(void)valueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
   NSInteger value = (NSInteger) (slider.value+0.005)*100;
   value = (value/2) * 2;  //round down if necessary
   [slider setValue:value/100.0 animated:NO];
}
```

To read the adjusted value if you need it, it would be `value/100.0`.
NB: Maybe you have to set the `continuous` property of the slider to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to know when the value of the `UISlider` increases/decreases exactly 0.02 so:

I Think you have to store the last value of your `UISlider`.

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
     UISlider * slider = (UISlider *) sender;
     //using fabs() because maybe value decreased
     if (fabs(slider.value - lastValue) == 0.02 ) 
     {
         //Your code here
     }
     lastVaule = slider.value;
}
```